# Fastest way to find open http/socks proxies in internet for datamining

Tags: ssh, proxy, http-proxy, socks, nmap

I want to find out open proxies in the internet which are misused to launch attack to our network. We are undergoing lots of L7 attacks created using these open proxies and we want to block these proxies temporarily by periodically detecting them. I see in [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_on_open_proxies/Guide_to_checking_open_proxies) that mere port scan can result into false positives:

> If the port is open there will usually be some response, but probably nothing very interesting. If a normal Nmap-portscan is used the ports will be said to be open, but this does not necessarily mean there is an open proxy. Nmap can, however, check via its scripts http-open-proxy and socks-open-proxy.
>
> An example would be:
> **nmap -P0 --script=socks-open-proxy --script=http-open-proxy.nse -p**

Using the socks-open-proxy and http-open-proxy script with nmap does reduce the false positives but it is extremely slow for my usecase. What is the fastest way to achieve similar true positive rate as using these 2 scripts with nmap and scan for all such open proxies? Any way the above nmap command itself can be made faster?